# Write a function pairs that takes a list l as an argument. It should return a new list, which contains all consecutive overlapping pairs of l

Tags: python

In other words, should contain all (l[i-1], l[i]) for all valid values of i, on order of ascending i. Clearly, the length of the result should be one less than the length of l (except, of course, if l was empty—then the result should also be empty, since there are no such pairs). For example, if l was equal to [1, ’a’, [’x’, 0], 2.0], then the result should be equal to [(1, ’a’), (’a’, [’x’, 0]), ([’x’, 0], 2.0)].Again, you should not modify the argument list in any way, and you should always return a new list. Furthermore, all pairs (i.e., tuples of length two) should contain (references to) the original elements of l.

This is what I have so far:

```
def pairs(l):
  if len(l) < 2: 
    return None 
  pairsList = []
  for i in range(1, len(l)):
    pairsList.append([l[i-1], l[i]])
  return pairsList
```

Comment: Perhaps this is how the question was phrased for you, in which case obviously you should follow the instructions, but note that PEP 8 [explicitly states](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) "Never use the character 'l' (lowercase letter el), ... as [a] single character variable name." It is difficult to read and work with especially when working with different fonts.

Answer (score 0):

According to you example, this is what you want:

```
def pairs(l):
    if len(l) < 2: 
        return None 
    pairsList = []
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        pairsList.append((l[i],l[i+1]))
    return pairsList
```

Comment: thanks! I keep getting an error though when I test it against an empty  result test. It gives me an assertion error that [] =! none. Do you know why this might be happening?